# How to calculate pressure drop in vertical pipe?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, viscosity

Given a fluids viscosity, dynamic viscosity, initial velocity, initial pressure, and a pipes length and diameter as well as knowledge that it is vertical, is it possible to calculate the pressure drop for the fluid in the pipe? I've been trying to use the steady mechanical energy equation, but so far can't get past the fact that I can't calculate the work done on the fluid, meaning that there are too many unknowns. Anyone got any ideas? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If $\tau$ is the shear stress at the wall, then, if the fluid is flowing downward,  $$P_{in}-P_{out}=\frac{4L}{D}\tau-\rho g L$$and, if the fluid is flowing upward, then$$P_{in}-P_{out}=\frac{4L}{D}\tau+\rho g L$$
$\tau$ is determined from the relationship between friction factor and Reynolds number.

Comment: This only works if your pipe is vertical, a sloped pipe would need to replace the second L for the height change.

Comment: @Gwydionforge What do the OP's words " as well as knowledge that it is vertical" mean to you?

Comment: You are correct, but I just thought I would clarify your equation because the next person reading this may not have the exact same situation. No offense intended.

Comment: @Gwydionforge No problem.  I just wanted to make sure that the OP didn't get confused.

Answer (score 0):

There is an entire class dedicated to this. You can look up fluid dynamics on the Khan Academy as a good place to start.

Here is a link:
https://www.khanacademy.org/science/physics/fluids

In non-flowing pipes the pressure is simple to determine you multiply the density times gravity times the height.

Drew K

Comment: The fluid in this case is flowing, will that affect the pressure since it isn't static, and that is a hydrostatic equation?

Comment: Yes that is a hydrostatic equation, the fluid flowing equations get complicated quick as you can see in Chester Miller 's answer. My advice is still to watch some video tutorials like the Khan Academy and others on you tube.